# How to solve "dataPaddingRequired" error CryptoSwift

Tags: swift, cryptography, aes, cryptoswift

I have `key = "somesomesomesome".md5()`, length is 32 bytes, `iv` is empty, trying to decrypt encrypted string using CryptoSwift:

```
let aes = try AES(key: key.bytes, blockMode: CBC(iv: []), padding: .noPadding)
let result = try aes.decrypt(encrypted)
let decrypted = String(bytes: result, encoding: .utf8)
```

getting error "dataPaddingRequired". What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Step 1. Don't use CryptoSwift, use CryptoKit or SwiftSodium. CS is awful.

Comment: @Woodstock or even better, use Apple's own solution, [CryptoKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit)

Comment: @DávidPásztor yup - said that , Cryptokit. SwiftSodium is better if using non NIST curves such as 25519

Comment: CryptoKit available only for iOS > 13.0, my target is 11.0, please help me find AES256 usage example of SwiftSodium

Comment: why did you set `.noPadding` set `.pkcs7`

Comment: Is your plaintext's length an exact multiple of 16-bytes? If not, how does your encryptor handle this? What is the code used to create this cipher text?

Answer (score 0):

Add this before setting up your AES:

```
let padding = Padding.noPadding.add(to: encrypted, blockSize: AES.blockSize)
```